# Leak caused by retain or something else? (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, sqlite

I'm using Leaks, and I believe I've narrowed down the problem, and I'm sure my inexperience has something to do with it.  If you see a failure in my logic (as in, there's obviously a simpler way to do this), please let me know.

In this case we're working with 3 classes, a Row class that describes rows in a database, a Database class that contains getRow, insertRow type functions, and a ViewController class.

inside Row.h:

```
@interface Row : NSObject {
int rowID;
NSString *FirstName;
NSString *LastName;

}

@property (nonatomic) int rowID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *FirstName; <--see comments below
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *LastName; <--see comments below

@end
```

Hopefully this one is pretty obvious, creates an object that i'm going to push data I pull from the database into.

inside Database.m

```
-(Row *) getRow {
NSLog(@"Inside getRow");
Row *holder = [[[Row alloc] init] autorelease];

...All the SQL stuff... (Select * from table where id = 1), etc.


char *first = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);
char *last = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2);

holder.rowID = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
holder.FirstName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:first];
holder.LastName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:last];

return holder;
}
```

Also, hopefully, fairly self explanatory.  Get a specific row from the database, put the info into a Row object (see Row.h).

inside ViewController.m

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    dataB = [[Database alloc] init];
    [dataB openDB];

    currentRow = [[dataB getRow] retain]; <--See comments below.

    firstNameLabel.text = currentRow.FirstName;

}

-(IBAction)btnGetLastName:(id)sender{
lastNameLabel.text = currentRow.LastName; <--See comments below.
[currentRow release];
currentRow = [dataB getRow];
}
```

Basically here the view controller give you the first name, and when you click on a button it displays the last name.

So, I'm leaking, and I've narrowed it down to every time I press btnGetLastName.  If I don't retain

```
currentRow = [[dataB getRow] retain];
```

I crash at

```
lastNameLabel.text = currentRow.LastName;
```

(Message sent to deallocated instance).

I've been banging my head into the wall for a couple days on this and I would really like to move forward from here, so if anyone can offer help, it would be greatly appreciated.  I will also say that this has all been a learning experience, so in some cases if you have to ask "Why did you do this?" the answer may be "because I'm dumb".  Hopefully the problem here is glaring to someone.

Comment: Also, I will add, in Row.h if I change '@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *FirstName;' to assign I could get the leak to go away if I also commented out 'lastNameLabel.text = currentRow.LastName;'.  I don't know if that makes any difference, but could the Row class be holding on even after the holder is released?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, there are a couple of things that I am seeing here that are incorrect.  First of all, you should probably make `currentRow` a retained property, that way you do not have to retain it and release it yourself.  Also, make sure your `-dealloc` method of your Row class look as follows:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    self.FirstName = nil;
    self.LastName = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Make your currentRow a property like so:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) Row * currentRow;
```

Then, assign it like `self.currentRow = aRow`.  Also note that you will need to set `self.currentRow = nil` in the dealloc method as well.  Your app is most likely crashing because you are not retaining currentRow on the line `currentRow = [dataB getRow];`.

I would also like to point out that it is bad convention to capitalize the first letter of an instance variable.

Comment: Yes. I was just typing something like this, but got distracted. This is the best use of properties; automating memory management problems.

Comment: This helped immensely.  The deallocation removed one of the leaks that was being called, so I'll ask this as a followup: There are some other layers to my program (moving in between views is the example I'll use).  It seems that by retaining autoreleasing 'holder' and retaining 'currentRow' and then releasing 'currentRow' when i change views (not in the above code, but it happens) holder sometimes doesn't get autoreleased and then it leaks.  Any ideas on how i can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

In the Row dealloc method are you releasing FirstName and LastName?

This seems like the obvious place in what you described for something to be over-retained.  Because you are doing `holder.FirstName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:first];` you are doing a retain using the synthesized setter.  If you don't explicitly release in dealloc() then FirstName and LastName will end up hanging around.

Comment: Will dealloc be called on the call to [holder release]?

Comment: dealloc will be called on your Row instance when the retain count is 0.  So life cycle: You init Row and autoRelease it in getRow: Then you retain it in the viewController so it's properly 1 at that point.  When you release it in the btnGetLastName it will be 0 and dealloc on the Row instance should be called.  In there you should explicitly release any property you have set as (retain) or that you know you have done an init on.

Answer (score 0):

currentRow = [[dataB getRow] retain];

is correct. If you did self.currentRow = [dataB getRow], (where currentRow was a retained synthesized property), that would also be correct. When you access member variables directly, you are performing an assign, bypassing the synthesized property setter.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `getRow`, you don't free the char arrays returned by the `sqlite3_` functions. That should be two leaks at least.

The crash if you don't retain the `currentRow` is the opposite: it gets freed alright, but before you are finished with it, and it must be retained to avoid that, also in `btnGetLastName`. Be sure to release it in `dealloc`.

Comment: According to the documentation:

"The pointers returned are valid until a type conversion occurs as described above, or until sqlite3_step() or sqlite3_reset() or sqlite3_finalize() is called. The memory space used to hold strings and BLOBs is freed automatically. Do not pass the pointers returned sqlite3_column_blob(), sqlite3_column_text(), etc. into sqlite3_free()."

Comment: OK, then there are no leaks there, unless he forgets to call sqlite3_step(), sqlite3_reset() or sqlite3_finalize(). I wonder how strings are freed automatically, though.

Comment: I didn't see a call to sqlite3_finalize().  So it probably does leak, but the finalize call most likely calls free().

Comment: Well, we didn't see all code anyway, so it is undetermined if it leaks or not. I still wonder how strings are being kept from leaking, in sqlite3.

Answer (score 0):

In the first call to `getRow` you retain the result (as you should).  Then when the button is pressed, you release it.  Good so far.  Then you `getRow` again, but don't retain it.

Comment: I wouldn't call that a leak. More like the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

There may be an issue with doing a release on an autorelease object. So I would do:
Row *holder = [[Row alloc] init];

and I trust you release currentRow in your dealloc method?